# how to create a hidden window by extending CWnd class in visual c++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, win32gui

Can any one help me in creating a Hidden window by extending CWnd class. I'm new to windows programming.
I've tried creating one, but the issue is code breaks down when trying to register the window class or creating a window.

```
class HiddenWindow : public CWnd
{
public:
   HiddenWindow();
   ~HiddenWindow();
protected:
   afx_msg LRESULT DoNOOP(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
   DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

};
This is my .cpp file

HiddenWindow::HiddenWindow()
{
   CString wcn = ::AfxRegisterWndClass(NULL);//code fails here because of AfxGetInstanceHandle( )
   BOOL created = this->CreateEx(0, wcn, _T("YourHiddenWindowClass"), 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL,HWND_MESSAGE,0);
}


HiddenWindow::~HiddenWindow()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(HiddenWindow, CWnd)
ON_MESSAGE(WM_USER + 1, DoNOOP)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

LRESULT HiddenWindow::DoNOOP(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   AfxMessageBox(_T("Test"));
   return LRESULT(true);
}
```

Comment: Creating a hidden window is normally just a matter of not showing it in the first place (e.g. by not calling `ShowWindow`). Please show some code if there's something you're having particular trouble with.

Comment: @JonathanPotter : hello Jonathan, i posted my code i've tried, it fails at AfxRegisterWndClass(NULL) because it is internally asserted.

Comment: Tell us were you get the ASSERT!

Comment: This sounds like you are instantiating a `HiddenWindow`-object with static storage duration. Objects with static storage duration are initialized before execution enters your `main`/`WinMain` functions. This may be too early for MFC to have fully initialized its required state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in MFC by overriding the Create, the constructor is
way too early
Try :

```
BOOL HiddenWindow::Create()
{  
    if (!CWnd::CreateEx(0, AfxRegisterWndClass(0),
        _T("HiddenWindow Notification Sink"),
        WS_OVERLAPPED, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TRACE0("Warning: unable to create HiddenWindow window!\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: @ Kjell Gunnar: my issue was my visual studio's project settings were not right, i was able to resolve it by creating a new MFC project.

Comment: @suj glad to hear your issue is solved! However you should not do things which can fail in the constructor because there is no way to return a bad status.

Comment: That is very wrong advice, Kjell: A constructor can fail and report the error by throwing an exception. Any system following the RAII idiom will have class with throwing constructors.

Answer (score 0):

you are not

> "extending CWnd class"

you are using C++ not C#, hence you are **deriving** class.

You do not really have to do it if you need basic functionality. Just call create passing windows styles you need without WS_VISIBLE, as you did. You have to however provide window class as an argument since your window is not a child window.

If you need to handle messages or need to implement different that default behavior you have to derive own class but still you do not have to override Create member.

You should never do anything but initialize member variables in the constructor. You should never try to allocate memory or call other functions the may allocate memory. you should not do anything that may cause irrevocable error. There is no way to gracefully exit if contractor fails.